# Percentage of wins

Tags: probability

Two people are playing a game.  Person $1$ has a $75%$ chance of winning each time.  If they play $5$ times, what is the probability that person $1$ will win exactly $4$ times?  Is it as simple as .$75^4$?

Comment: No - you need the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: for *each* way (e.g. (W,W,W,L,W) of getting exactly 4 wins the probability is $0.75^4$, but there are several different ways to get these 4 wins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a binomial distribution in which you want to find out the probability of exactly how many times something will succeed, you'll need to use this:

$$\binom{n}{r}*p^r*q^{n-r}$$

Where $n =$ number of trials,  $r =$ number of specific events you wish to obtain,  $p =$ probability that the event will occur,  and $q =$ probability that the event will not occur ($q = 1 - p$, the complement of the event).

In this case, $n=5$, $r=4$, $p=0.75$, $q=0.25$, so

$$\binom{5}{4}*0.75^4*0.25^{5-4}\approx0.3955$$

Answer (score 1):

To win exactly 4 games you have to loose 1 So the probabilty of winning the first 4 games and losing the last is:

$\left( \dfrac{3}{4} \right)^4 \cdot \dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{81}{1024}$

Now we dont care about the order we could lose any of the 5 games so there are 5 ways we could do this making the probability

$\dfrac{81}{1024} \cdot 5 = \dfrac{405}{1024} \approx 39.55\% $